# Is it possible to use va_list method twice in a function?

Tags: c++, formatting

I want to use the va_list method twice, in one function. can I do that?

```
#include <cstdarg>

void printFDS(int num_fds, ... , const char *fmt, ...) {

    va_list fds, args;
    va_start(fds, num_fds);
    va_start(args, fmt);

    for (int i = 0; i < num_fds; i++) {
        vsprintf(va_arg(fds, FILE*), fmt, args);
    }
    va_end(args);
    va_end(fds);
}
```

So I'll be able to call that function like that:

```
printFDS(1, stderr, "Error: %s\n", stderror(errno));
```

or
    `printFDS(2, stderr, otherFD, "Error: %s\n", stderror(errno));`

while `FILE *otherFD = fopen ("somefile", "w");`

My purpose: to print information, on a list of fd's..

Thanks

Comment: you could pass the list of fd's as a collection of some kind (array, list, set, ...)

Comment: why the C tag when this is a C++ question? And note that using containers are by far superior to va_lists.

Comment: How do you envision it?

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze: `#include <cstdarg>`

Comment: No, I mean, passing and retrieval of parameters using this scheme.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze: Ah, pardon.

Comment: @phresnel Sorry, that question wasn't directed to you.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze: I am the one to beg for pardon :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do this directly. What you can do, though, is

```
void printFDS(int num_fds, ...)
```

and in your function, use `va_copy` to get two `va_list` variables. In one, read the `FILE *`s. In the other, first skip `num_fds` `FILE *`s, then use `va_arg` to get the format string.

You will need to do some more copying to ensure that that second `va_list` isn't trashed by `vfprintf`, you can again use `va_copy` for that.

Answer (score 5):

That's not possible, the ellipsis (the three dots) must be only once and only last.

---

If you have a C++11 capable compiler, you might be able to do it with an [initializer list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Initializer_lists) and `std::vector` for the first argument:

```
void printFDS(const std::vector<FILE*>& files, const char* fmt, ...)
{
    // ...
}
```

You could cal it as

```
printFDS({ stderr, otherFilePointer }, "Error: %s\n", std::strerror(errno));
```